# JNI problems in web service with JBOSS 5.1 and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface, jboss5.x, loadlibrary

My team is creating a web service in Eclipse (Indigo with build id: 20110615-0604) targeted for the JBOSS 5.1 (non-negotiable server and version as defined by the customer) application server. My company's proprietary algorithms are in a shared library compiled on a Linux 64 bit machine and I need to access them from my web service. I've created my JNI files with SWIG. The resultant java files are compiled and dropped in a jar. The jar is included in the EAR and seen by all projects in Eclipse. The resultant MODULE_wrap.cpp file  is compiled and included in my .so - call it libmylib.so

My web service, when it starts up, calls a static class to load my shared library via System.loadLibrary("mylib"). There are no issues with this. My library is only loaded once and there are no exceptions. I've checked that the path to my library is in the java.library.path property - as expected since loadLibrary worked.

The resultant SWIG files work with a test driver outside of Eclipse - that is we can access native functions in the library. This makes me believe that the function names created by SWIG and the native mapping are being done correctly. However, when using Eclipse to create and deploy the web service EAR to JBOSS we get an UnsatisfiedLinkError complaining that a C++ constructor from my library cannot be found.

**SWIG line of my makefile**

```
swig -c++ -java -package my.package -outdir java/my/package -Isrc -Iinc -o src/MODULE_wrap.cpp src/MODULE.i
```

**MODULE.i**

```
    /* File : MODULE.i */

%module MODULE

%include "arrays_java.i"

%apply double[] {double *};

%{

\#include "MyCPPHeader.hh"

%}

%include "MyCPPHeader.hh
```

**My creation of the shared objects:**

```
g++ -fPIC -c -Idir1 -I. -Idir2 -Idir3 -Idir4 -Idir5 -O2 -DMACRO_DEF  src/MyCPPSource.cpp -o obj/MyCPPSource.osh

g++ -fPIC -c -Idir1 -I. -Idir2 -Idir3 -Idir4 -Idir5 -O2 -DMACRO_DEF  src/MODULE_wrap.cpp -o obj/MODULE_wrap.osh
```

**My creation of the library**

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux5E/lib64 obj/MyCPPSource.osh obj/MODULE_wrap.osh -o lib/libmylib.so
```

**SWIG .JAR**

If I do a jar -tf of the jar containing the SWIG generated JAVA files all of the necessary classes in the appropriate package directory structure are there. Eclipse/JBOSS don't complain about any of these sources - only when it attempts to find the call labeled as "native" in the JNI class.

**The java class that loads the library. It lives in JBoss'_Home/server/default/lib within a JAR**

```
public class LibLoader {
static 
{
    try
    {
        System.loadLibrary("mylib");
        System.out.println("Loaded " + System.mapLibraryName("mylib"));
    }
    catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
    {
        System.out.println("Got unsat link error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Got exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public LibLoader() {}
}
```

**How that LibLoader class is used from my web service - which is implemented as a java singleton:**

```
public static WebService getInstance()
{
    // loads library once outside the service
if (m_libLoader == null)
    m_libLoader = new LibLoader(); 

// Create the singleton instance
if (m_instance == null)
    m_instance = new WebService(); 

    // Create an object as defined in my library and accessed with JNI
if (m_libraryObject == null)
{
    // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE UnsatisfiedLinkError!!!!!
    m_libraryObject = new MyObjectFromSharedLibrary();
}

return m_instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Instead of bundling the SWIG JNI wrapper JAR with my EAR I put it in the same directory on the server as my LibLoader JAR and low and behold it worked.